# How to define a syntax region for the initial character in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

```
a - this is a
b - this is not c
* - it is *
```

How can I highlight `a`, `-`, and the following description, respectively? I know little about the syntax definition in vim. Here is my attempt:

```
syn region MyMinus start="-" end="\s"
hi def link MyMinus String
```

But I failed to highlight the initial character and the description section. What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "repectively"? Do you want to match all lines that begin with a letter, then a minus sign? Or do you want to highlight differently what is before the minus sign, and after it?

Comment: @yolenoyer I want to highlight three sections: the minus sign, what is before and after it. And I merely succeed to highlight the minus sign at present.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it, using the `contains=...` and `contained` keywords:

```
" Add some highlight defs:
hi link MyLeftPart  SpecialKey
hi link MyMinus     Operator
hi link MyRightPart String

" Match the whole lines, and make the given highlight work only
" with lines with this format: "x - blah blah..." :
syn match MyLeftPart  /^. - .*/  contains=MyMinus

" Leave the very first char highlighted with MyLeftPart, and
" highlight the rest with MyMinus:
syn match MyMinus     /.\zs.*/   contains=MyRightPart contained

" Leave the minus highlighted with MyMinus, and highlight the rest
" with MyRightPart:
syn match MyRightPart / - \zs.*/ contained
```

Of course you may modify the three given patterns to better suit your needs (for example, by replacing `-` by `\s\+-\s\+`, or by removing the `^` in order to make the highlight work even with lines shifted to the right).

You may also prefer another solution, for example by using the `matchadd()` function instead of `:syn match`.

Comment: Thanks. But have you tested it? It seems to fail to work in my case.

Comment: Of course I did; can you precise about what happens when it fails please